# Is that possible to connect to a remote server through Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a scenario such that I need to connect to Analysis Services of SQL Server Management Studio to run MDX queries installed in remote server.

Is it possible to connect to a remote server through Robot framework?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the [robot framework database library](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) to talk to most databases.

Comment: Hi Bryan ,                                                                                                Thanks for your response.Is that possible to connect to a remote desktop through robot framework?

Comment: "connect to a remote desktop" is too vague, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Right now, I am working on Robot Framework and I need to do same thing that you have asked in your question. Here, I found one documentation and library on git that could be useful for RDP but I am not sure that will satisfy your requirement or not.

[PythonRemoteServer](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer)

I am newbie to Robot Framework but I'll update you if i found anything related to your question.